# Задать двумерный список из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки

Нужно задать двумерный массив из текстового файла:

```
7 8
0 0 1 0 -1 -1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
-1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 -1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

7 и 8 - количсевто строк и столбцов соответственно, остальное - в двумерный массив. 
Я пытаюсь реализовать это таким образом.

```
file = open('input.txt', 'r').read()
M = file[0]    # количество строк (7)
N = file[2]    # количество столбцов (8)

lines = open('input.txt', 'r').readlines()
for i in M:
   for n in lines[i]:
      if n == 0 or n == -1 or n == 1:
          map[[i], [n]] = n
```

Результат должен выглядеть типа `map[[4], [5]] = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что данные могут не совпадать с размерностью, указанной в начале файла (то есть, их будет больше), то можно попробовать такой вариант:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    ax1, ax2 = f.readline().split() #reading dimensions
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(int(ax1)):
        lines[i] = (lines[i].rstrip()).split(' ')[:int(ax2)]
    lines=lines[:int(ax1)]  #вот это криво, конечно
```

И, если вывести получившейся двумерный список:

```
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Получим:

```
['0', '0', '1', '0', '-1', '-1', '0', '1']
['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
['-1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0']
['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '0']
['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

**Update:** 
Забыл упомянуть, что полученные значения - строковые переменные.
Если нужны целые числа, то можно заменить пятую строку на:

```
lines[i] = list(map(int,(lines[i].rstrip()).split(' ')[:int(ax2)]))
```

Comment: Идея хорошая, но в результате требуется аналог кординат, а не строки. К примеру   map[[4], [5]] = 1        /   Как можно такое реализовать?

Comment: @Adrian - все так и будет: print(lines[0][4]) к примеру, покажет -1

Comment: понял, огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Для Python два числа в первой строке не нужны, поэтому `in in_file[1:]`

```
in_file = open('INPUT.TXT').read().splitlines()
map = [line.split() for line in in_file[1:]]

# print для показать
print(map[0][4])
```

Но если прям очень большое желание зафиксировать размерность то:

```
in_file = open('INPUT.TXT').read().splitlines()
n, m = [int(i) for i in in_file[0].split()]
mp = [in_file[i].split()[:n + 1] for i in range(1, m)]
print(mp[0][4])
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что два числа в первой строке не нужны? А если в файле данных больше, чем указанная размерность?

Comment: Потому, что этих задач я вагон перерешал и, поверьте, они там не нужны. Эта задача с сайта, где задачи можно решать с помощью разных ЯП, и для каких-то они нужны, поэтому они есть.